# DC or District of Columbia in State List?

Tags: user-behavior, text

When making a drop down to select state is it generally preferred to put DC or District of Columbia? Should you just go with DC if all other states are abbreviated and District of Columbia otherwise?

I feel like for most states the thought process is Full Name --> Abbreviation but with DC, I think people generally think Abbreviation --> Full Name

Comment: Could you have both?

Comment: What are you doing with the rest of the states?  If you are using the two later abbreviations for the rest, use DC.  If you are using the whole name of the state/territory, use District of Columbia. There is no reason to do it differently then the rest.  People who live in the Distric of Columbia know what the abbreviation is, they will find it either way.

Comment: @sn3ll please see the second sentence in my question

Comment: @RedSirius I could but that seems redundant?

Comment: I think DC should be on the state list because it's the hekin' capital but if you need the abbreviation, just use DC bro 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go with DC. As a resident of the city that deals with these drop downs often, I am almost always looking for DC. District of Columbia is an okay choice, but DC is what it's called primarily and what most people probably look for.

I wouldn't choose Washington, DC, if only for the reason that few drop downs seem to use this so residents probably aren't used to it.

Answer (score 1):

**Use DC unless you can use Washington, DC.**

Despite the formal name of "District of Columbia," DC is more commonly referred to as "Washington, DC." when not abbreviated.  Your users may look for this when searching the list.  [From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington,_D.C.):

> "**Washington, D.C.**, formally the **District of Columbia** and commonly referred to as **Washington**, **'the District'**, or simply **D.C.**.."

Depending on the application, consider the [autocomplete pattern](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/Autocomplete) to address the problem of ambiguity when a user might refer to the same entity in several different ways.